# How to increase font-weight in react-circular-progressbar?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-circular-progressbar library, unfortunately, I'm unable to change font-weight of text. Although I'm able to manage text size using textSize property in styles object but font-weight property isn't working. I tried its variations as well,(e.g. textWeight, fontWeight) but nothing seems to be working in favour of mine.

Here is the code for the component:

```js
import React from "react";
import { CircularProgressbar, buildStyles } from "react-circular-progressbar";
import { CircularProgressbarWithChildren } from "react-circular-progressbar";
import "react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css";

function Circular_progress_bar() {
  const percentage = 50;

  return (
    <div>
      <CircularProgressbar
        value={percentage}
        text={`${percentage}%`}
        background
        backgroundPadding={0}
        styles={buildStyles({
          textSize: "2.5rem",
          textShadow: "0 0 2px #000",
          textWeight: "700 !important",
          fontWeight: "900 !important",
          backgroundColor: "#102558",
          textColor: "#fff",
          pathColor: "#00ade9",
          trailColor: "transparent",
          transform: "rotate(90deg)",
          transformOrigin: "center center",
          rotation: 1 / 7 + 1 / 10,
          text: {
            // Text color
            fill: "#1d1d1d",
            // Text size
            fontSize: "2.5rem",
            fontWeight: "900 !important",
            textShadow: "0 0 2px #000",
          },
        })}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Circular_progress_bar;
```

Also, I want to change the background of the completed section in the circle and I couldn't find such functionality in any of the pre-available types.
Here is the link to codesandbox for better explanation: https://codesandbox.io/s/progressbar-fontweight-x4xnuh

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this using `buildStyles` by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/kevinsqi/react-circular-progressbar/blob/master/src/buildStyles.ts), according to the docs this function can only be used

> to configure the most common style changes

This means that `buildStyles` is a shorthand. You'll need to provide the elements of which you want to customize the style. See the [docs second example](https://github.com/kevinsqi/react-circular-progressbar#using-the-styles-prop). You can change the `fontWeight` like so, **without** using `buildStyles`.

```js
<CircularProgressbar
  value={percentage}
  text={`${percentage}%`}
  background
  backgroundPadding={0}
  styles={{
    ...
    text: {
      ...
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
  }}
/>
```

[Live preview](https://codesandbox.io/s/progressbar-fontweight-forked-7t7qdp)

Comment: Can you please edit the codesandbox accordingly? Do we need a separate styles object for this or move other properties in this as well?

Comment: You just need to remove `buildStyles(` and the other `)` from the `styles` property

Comment: No, it doesn't work this way. All other properties also stop working if we remove buildStyles function.

Comment: @Fuaad I've included a preview and updated my answer accordingly

Comment: This is nice, it'd be appreciated if you could adjust its trail's rotation as well. Mean I want to start it from bottom and move upwards from both sides, also I want to fill it's corresponsing background with some color.

Comment: @Fuaad not really part of your question but I've updated the sandbox, not sure what background you mean, for the circle you can use the `background` prop to style and for the square around the circle you can use the `root` prop. I recommend doing some reading on the docs.

Comment: Actually, I want to set the background of the circle that comes under the completed path, and move this path from both sides equally (currently this is moving from left-side only). Please have a look at this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/circular-progressbar-demo-s8enfw?file=/src/App.js